# Create a collection in mongodb stitch app

Tags: mongodb, react-native, mongodb-stitch, stitch

Is there a way to create a collection in MongoDB stitch app in react-native. I tried the normal MongoDB way

```
const stitchClient = Stitch.getAppClient(myAppID);
const mongodb = stitchClient.getServiceClient(RemoteMongoClient.factory, "mongodb-atlas")
    .db("ToDo");
        // console.log("mongodb is ", mongodb);
mongodb.createCollection("test", (err, res) => {
   if (err) {
       throw ("Error creating a collection : ", err);
   }
   console.log("Collection creted");
});
```

But then react-native keeps giving this error :

> TypeError: undefined is not a function(near 'MongoDB.createCollection...')

Answer (score 0):

> But then react-native keeps giving this error

[RemoteMongoDatabase](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch-sdks/js-react-native/4/interfaces/remotemongodatabase.html) does not have `createCollection` method. It's not a function that you could call/invoke.

Conceptually, worth mentioning that [MongoDB Stitch](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/) prevents access to your data by default. First you need to create a collection first, and define it's [Rules](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/#collection-rules). You can create a collection either manually from `mongo` shell or from Stitch Rules UI. Please note that you must define at least one role before you can successfully query a collection.

See also [Stitch: Define Roles And Permissions](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/define-roles-and-permissions/) for step by step procedure on how to create Rules.